# Sequence of Integers Generated Using a Residue Class Set Number Sieve

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

This is a problem concerning application of a number sieve consisting of an infinitude of residue classes to generate an integer sequence of numbers, analogous to the Sieve of Eratosthenes used for generating prime numbers.

The set of residue classes used for the sieve are defined by $(4n-1)x-n$ that is

$3x-1$, $7x-2$, $11x-3$, $15x-4$  etc. where $x$ and $n$ are non-zero positive integers.

The first few numbers remaining after applying the sieve are:

$$1,3,4,6,7,9,10,13,15,16,18,21,22,24,25 \tag{1}$$

OEIS lists [this sequence](https://oeis.org/A094178) (conjecturally!) as the numbers $n$ such that $4n+1$ is divisible only by primes of the form $4m+1$, that is Pythagorean Primes (primes that can be written as the sum of two squares).

**Is there a way of proving that these two infinite sequences are identical or not?**

**Update**

The same sequence (1) is generated by taking the complement of the integer sequence [A124934](https://oeis.org/A124934)  (as previous OEIS wb page suggests) which are numbers of the form $4mn-m-n$ where $m$ and $n$ are non-zero positive integers.

The complementary sequence to the Pythagorean Primes are primes of the form $4n+3$

If we take $t_m=4(4mn-m-n)+1$

with $m=1$, $m=2$, $m=3$etc.
$$t_1=4(4 n-1-n)+1=12n-3=3\times(4n-1)$$
$$t_2=4(4\times 2 n-2-n)+1=28n-7=7\times(4n-1)$$
$$t_3=4(4\times 3 n-3-n)+1=44n-11=11\times(4n-1)$$
and so on...to give
$$t_m=4(4\times m n-m-n)+1=(4m-1)\times(4n-1)$$

As $t_m$, generated from the complementary sequence of integers to (1), is only divisible by primes of the form $4m+3$ or $4n+3$, starting from $n=0$ and $m=0$, does this then prove that for each $n$ in (1) when also in the form $4n+1$ can only be divisible by Pythagorean primes of the form $4m+1$.

There must be a much neater way of expressing such a proof.